# Unused argument error in ifelse statement using R

Tags: r, if-statement, subset, rbind

I'm trying to make a new data frame based on an ifelse statement.  I'm checking in 1 dataframe to see whether a field contains a string.  If it does, I then want to add rows from that dataframe to another data frame, using filter, subset, and rbind methods:

This works:

```
  #Check to see if field contains string. 
  timeline.data.2 <-ifelse(grepl(1043-1, prescription.data$case_id), 
                                timeline.data <- timeline.data %>%
                                  filter(case_id==1043-1),          

                                "do nothing")
```

This does not:

```
  #Check to see if field contains string. 
  timeline.data.2 <-ifelse(grepl(1043-1, prescription.data$case_id), 
                                timeline.data <- timeline.data %>%
                                  filter(case_id==1043-1),
                                timeline.data <-subset(timeline.data, select = c(event,group,start,end,color,tooltip)),
                                timeline.data <- subset(prescription.data, select = c(event,group,start,end,color,tooltip)),
                                timeline.data <- rbind(timeline.data, prescription.data),
                                "do nothing")
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error in ifelse(grepl(1043 - 1, prescription.data$case_id), timeline.data <- timeline.data %>%  : 
unused argument ("do nothing")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The assignment (` timeline.data <-`) would not work inside `ifelse`

Comment: i've tried it without, and still no luck. i.e. subset(timeline.data, select = c(event,group,start,end,color,tooltip))

Comment: Also, your 'yes' is a data.fframe instead of a vector

Comment: if the condition is met, I just want to run the subset/filter/cbind, etc. thoughts?

Comment: Are you checking for `any` elements?

Comment: i'm just checking whether a column contains a variable.  If it does, I want to filter it, subset it and another df, and then use rbind.

Comment: I didn't understand the `subset` steps below.  Is it on the same condition or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to use `if/else`

```
library(dplyr)
if(any(grepl("1043-1", prescription.data$case_id))) {

    timeline.data <- timeline.data %>%
                        filter(grepl("1043-1", case_id))

 } else "do nothing"
```

Comment: Thanks.  What is the meaning of "any" here?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 I used `any` because `if/else` expects a single TRUE/FALSE as input.  So, if there are any values of '1043-1', it is aksing to filter the rows

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` takes exactly three arguments. You appear to be providing... 6? I think? That's what "unused argument" means: you gave it too many arguments. That's why your *first* example works, only three arguments.

You use `ifelse` to pick between values as you run down a vector. It's good for simple jobs like replacing NAs: `ifelse(is.na(my_data), 'bad value', my_data)`.

After you clarify what you're using `ifelse` for, [**indent and line-break your code properly**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html). Then you'll be able to interpret what's an argument, and what's not, and error messages like this will make much more sense.

If I run your code through `styler` it prints it like this:

```
# Check to see if field contains string.
timeline.data.2 <- ifelse(grepl(1043 - 1, prescription.data$case_id),
  timeline.data <- timeline.data %>%
    filter(case_id == 1043 - 1),
  timeline.data <- subset(timeline.data, select = c(event, group, start, end, color, tooltip)),
  timeline.data <- subset(prescription.data, select = c(event, group, start, end, color, tooltip)),
  timeline.data <- rbind(timeline.data, prescription.data),
  "do nothing"
)
```

Now it's MUCH EASIER to see all those lines, ending in commas, going into `ifelse`.